# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, google-maps-android-api-2

I am new to android maps developer. I need to run my app onto my device but i am getting the error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.daniel.pencarikakus/com.daniel.pencarikakus.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView"

Code activity_maps.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:text="@string/map_type"
            android:id="@+id/Mtype"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:onClick="changeType" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="338dp"
            android:layout_height="539dp" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="39dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/zoom_in"
                android:id="@+id/Bzoomin"
                android:onClick="onZoom" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="41dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/zoom_out"
                android:id="@+id/Bzoomout"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:onClick="onZoom" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/show_location"
                android:layout_width="26dp"
                android:layout_height="443dp"
                android:text="@string/show_my_location"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code MapsActivity.java

```
package com.daniel.pencarikakus;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Button show_location;
    private TextView textView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private String[] perms = {"android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
            "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
            "android.permission.INTERNET"};

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        show_location = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_location);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                textView.setText("\n" + location.getLatitude() + " ,  " + location.getLongitude());
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+ location.getLatitude()+ "," + location.getLongitude()+ " (" + "ali" + ")"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        if(shouldAskPermission()) {
            requestPermissions(perms, 1);
        }else {
            configureButton();
        }

    }

    private void configureButton() {
        show_location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListener);
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean shouldAskPermission(){
        return(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1 :
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    configureButton();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Location Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();                 }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    public void onZoom(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.Bzoomin) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
        }
        if (view.getId() == R.id.Bzoomout) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
        }
    }

    public void changeType(View view) {
        if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL) {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        } else
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-6.3808998, 106.8560731)).title("Kakus SPBU Pertamina HJ. Juanda Depok"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-6.392380, 106.842627)).title("Kakus SPBU Pertamina Proklamasi Depok 2"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-6.405508, 106.851353)).title("Kakus SPBU Pertamina BBM Samping Giant Depok"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-6.404099, 106.8375171)).title("Kakus SPBU Pertamina Tole Iskandar Depok"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-6.399919, 106.825987)).title("Kakus SPBU Pertamina Siliwangi Samping RS. Hermina Depok"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-6.384004, 106.829607)).title("Kakus SPBU Pertamina KemiriMuka Margonda Depok"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-6.381064, 106.830799)).title("Kakus SPBU SHELL KemiriMuka Margonda Depok"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-6.374302, 106.832806)).title("Kakus SPBU Pertamina Samping KFC Margonda Depok"));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-6.398421, 106.808525), 14.9f));
    }
}
```

Code SplashScreen.java

```
package com.daniel.pencarikakus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        int splashInterval = 1000;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);


                //jeda selesai Splashscreen
                this.finish();
            }

            private void finish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }, splashInterval);

    }

}
```

Code SplashScreen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/pencarikakus"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/splashscreen" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this Code AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.daniel.pencarikakus">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="PencariKakus"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!-- Splash screen -->
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="PencariKakus"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:noHistory="true" >


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="PencariKakus">
        </activity>
        <!--memasukan elemen Activity dengan atribut configChanges dan theme-->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and the last is my summary log from my XIAOMI MI4i

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.daniel.pencarikakus/com.daniel.pencarikakus.SplashScreen}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:637)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2159)
    at com.daniel.pencarikakus.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5982)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
    ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:611)
    ... 23 more
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 154050816 byte allocation with 12669460 free bytes and 109MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:613)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:446)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
    at android.content.res.Resources.createFromResourceStream(Resources.java:2762)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2463)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2365)
    at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:393)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:751)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:131)
    ... 26 more
```

and i got error to from my MapsActivity.java

```
private void configureButton() {
    show_location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListener);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError` - Looks like the image on the `ImageView` is too big.

Comment: By the way, you can refer to making a [mcve], but basically, if the problem is the XML, the Java code typically doesn't need added to the question

Comment: thanks!! worked for me. i have read from your links. thanks cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size of your image is too large.
You should resize your image in SplashScreen.xml.
I hope this gonna be work.

Comment: This should be a comment ..

Comment: This is answer also

Comment: You saw what Mike M said?

Comment: Yeah...thats why I m post my answer